# Running GUI program from within Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Is there a way I can start a standalone GUI program from within my javascript code? What I intend is to display a button when in a particular website, which when clicked, opens up my GUI program and passes the URL to it, kinda like Internet Download Manager(IDM) does it.

Comment: Your GUI program needs to register a custom URL scheme on the OS level, like `mailto:`, `skype:` or `steam:` (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#Official_IANA-registered_schemes)

Comment: Is your question: "How can I launch a native application from a browser?" Everything you can see on the screen is GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app registers as a handler for specific URL schemes, then opening a link using one of those URL schemes should do.

For instance, if your app says it can handle the `myscheme` scheme, then opening `myscheme:somedata` URL should trigger opening that app.